# Typescript side-by-side editing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Having used side by side editing for Typescript and its compiled Javascript output using Web Essentials 2013 in Visual Studio 2013, now that I have updated to Visual Studio 2015 the side by side capability seems to have completely vanished, does anyone know how to get it working? Or has it been dropped completely?!

Comment: This was a specific Web Essentials feature and it's not available in VS2015.

Comment: So Web Essentials has dropped it? How annoying!

Answer (score 4):

You can get this functionality without needing any plugin in any version of VS.

First allow changes to be reloaded in visual studio options.

[image: Options]

Then you can open a tab with the JS output and place it next to the typescript tab.